# How to invalidate 'expired' Firebase Instance ID Token

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

AFAIK, the Firebase Instance Token will be refreshed under the following 4 conditions:

1. App deletes Instance ID
2. App is restored on a new device
3. User uninstalls/reinstall the app
4. User clears app data

Suppose a user is using Token A as his 'FCM address'. Every time when he logs in the app, he will register the Token A to the Firestore along with this user's UUID so user-specific cloud message can be sent to him. When he logs out, the system will fire a request to firestore for removing the token A record.

Now, when the user reinstalls the app, the instance id is refreshed and a new Token B is generated. The Token A becomes useless. Unfortunately, if the user does not log out before the uninstallation, token A will stay in the firestore forever.

Any workaround or wiser way to handle this case?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Keeping your token registry up to date requires two steps:

1. Remove outdated tokens from your application code.
2. Check for outdated tokens and remove them when you *send* messages.

Your approach of removing a token that is no longer used, is #1.

The second step though is to remove tokens from your registry/database when you get a `messaging/invalid-registration-token` or `messaging/registration-token-not-registered` response when trying to send a message to it. The [functions-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L77) contains a great example of this:

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then((response) => {
  // For each message check if there was an error.
  const tokensToRemove = [];
  response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
    const error = result.error;
    if (error) {
      console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
      // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
      if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
          error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
        // TODO: remove the token from your registry/database
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The above code uses the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js, but the same logic could also be applied to other platforms or when sending messages through the HTTPS endpoints.

Comment: It seems there is no way even firebase could know that user uninstalls app and associated token would become no longer in use however I'm guessing that firebase automatically invalidate tokens that are not used for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

As Frank mentioned in his answer you can remove them when sending messages and getting not registered error.

Here how I delete outdated registration tokens when registering a new one using C#.

First of all using **Instance ID API** I get token info as following:

```
 public async Task<FCMTokenInfo> GetTokenInfoAsync(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://iid.googleapis.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", String.Format("key={0}", "your-authorization-key"));

            var uri = $"/iid/info/{token}";

            var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            var responseStr = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (httpResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //log 400 bad request and do whatever you want
            }

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FCMTokenInfo>(responseStr);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log the exception
            throw;
        }
    }
```

FCMTokenInfo.cs

```
public class FCMTokenInfo
{
    public string Application { get; set; }
    public string Subtype { get; set; }
    public string Scope { get; set; }
    public string AuthorizedEntity { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
}
```

And then inside the service that saves registration tokens inside the database:

```
//this method gets called when a new token is sent by the javascript web app
public async Task AddTokenAsync(Guid accountId, string token)
    {
        try
        {

            //getting TokenInfo of the current token(or refreshed one for that app)
            var fcmTokenInfo = await firebaseServices.GetTokenInfoAsync(token);

            //adding the current token
            dbContext.FcmRegisterationTokens.Add(new FcmRegisterationToken
            {
                Token = token,
                AccountId = accountId,
                AddingDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                Application = fcmTokenInfo.Application,
                Subtype = fcmTokenInfo.Subtype,
                AuthorizedEntity = fcmTokenInfo.AuthorizedEntity,
                Scope = fcmTokenInfo.Scope,
                Platform = fcmTokenInfo.Platform
            });

            var outdatedTokens = await dbContext.FcmRegisterationTokens
                                         .Where(x => x.AccountId == accountId
                                                  && x.Application == fcmTokenInfo.Application
                                                  && x.Platform == fcmTokenInfo.Platform
                                         ).ToListAsync();

           //remove them
            dbContext.FcmRegisterationTokens.RemoveRange(outdatedTokens);

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             throw;
        }

    }
```